# How is the graph on the NCrunch Risk/Progress window calculated?

Tags: c#, ncrunch

Can anyone shed any light on what the curve on the chart means, what the shaded area means, and what the axes are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a projection of risk over time.  There's some documentation describing this in the NCrunch wiki: http://wiki.ncrunch.net/Risk-Progress-Bar.ashx